# how to check isinstance for date in django python

Tags: python, django, datetime, validation, django-models

I have date data in variable date_var as

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Model:
  created_date    =   models.DateTimeField

date_var = model.created_date.date()
```

however when I check isinstance of c with datetime or with models.DateTimeField it returns false

```
isinstance(date_var,datetime)
// False

isinstance(date_var,models.DateTimeField)
// False
```

what is the way to check if c is instance of date?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `type` instead? `type(date_var) is datetime`

Comment: can you try with `isinstance(date_var, datetime.date)`

Comment: `model.created_date` is a `datetime`, `model.created_date.date()` is a `date`

Comment: the answer provided by @thanh worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, type of `date_var` is `date` not `datetime`.

If you want to check type `date`, you can do like below

```
from datetime import date

isinstance(date_var, date)
```